# Client-server synchronization pattern / algorithm?

Tags: client-server, data-synchronization

I have a feeling that there must be client-server synchronization patterns out there. But i totally failed to google up one.

Situation is quite simple - server is the central node, that multiple clients connect to and manipulate same data. Data can be split in atoms, in case of conflict, whatever is on server, has priority (to avoid getting user into conflict solving). Partial synchronization is preferred due to potentially large amounts of data.

Are there any patterns / good practices for such situation, or if you don't know of any - what would be your approach?

Below is how i now think to solve it:
Parallel to data, a modification journal will be held, having all transactions timestamped. 
When client connects, it receives all changes since last check, in consolidated form (server goes through lists and removes additions that are followed by deletions, merges updates for each atom, etc.).
Et voila, we are up to date.

Alternative would be keeping modification date for each record, and instead of performing data deletes, just mark them as deleted.

Any thoughts?

Comment: agreed there is very little talk of patterns for this sort of thing... even though this scenario is pretty common

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You should look at how distributed change management works.  Look at SVN, CVS and other repositories that manage deltas work.

You have several use cases.

- Synchronize changes.  Your change-log (or delta history) approach looks good for this.  Clients send their deltas to the server; server consolidates and distributes the deltas to the clients.  This is the typical case.  Databases call this "transaction replication".
- Client has lost synchronization.  Either through a backup/restore or because of a bug.  In this case, the client needs to get the current state from the server without going through the deltas.  This is a copy from master to detail, deltas and performance be damned.  It's a one-time thing; the client is broken; don't try to optimize this, just implement a reliable copy.
- Client is suspicious.  In this case, you need to compare client against server to determine if the client is up-to-date and needs any deltas.

You should follow the database (and SVN) design pattern of sequentially numbering every change.  That way a client can make a trivial request ("What revision should I have?") before attempting to synchronize.  And even then, the query ("All deltas since 2149") is delightfully simple for the client and server to process.

Comment: May you sir explain what a delta exactly is? My guess would be that's a hash/timestamp combination ... I would like to hear from u sir.

Comment: A delta refers to the change between two revisions. For example, if a user's name has changed then the delta can be something like {revision: 123, name: "John Doe"}

Answer (score 37):

As part of the team, I did quite a lot of projects which involved data syncing, so I should be competent to answer this question.

Data syncing is quite a broad concept and there are way too much to discuss. It covers a range of different approaches with their upsides and downsides. Here is one of the possible classifications based on two perspectives: Synchronous / Asynchronous, Client/Server / Peer-to-Peer. Syncing implementation is severely dependent on these factors, data model complexity, amount of data transferred and stored, and other requirements. So in each particular case the choice should be in favor of the simplest implementation meeting the app requirements.

Based on a review of existing off-the-shelf solutions, we can delineate several major classes of syncing, different in granularity of objects subject to synchronization:

- Syncing of a whole document or database is used in cloud-based applications, such as Dropbox, Google Drive or Yandex.Disk. When the user edits and saves a file, the new file version is uploaded to the cloud completely, overwriting the earlier copy. In case of a conflict, both file versions are saved so that the user can choose which version is more relevant.
- Syncing of key-value pairs can be used in apps with a simple data structure, where the variables are considered to be atomic, i.e. not divided into logical components. This option is similar to syncing of whole documents, as both the value and the document can be overwritten completely. However, from a user perspective a document is a complex object composed of many parts, but a key-value pair is but a short string or a number. Therefore, in this case we can use a more simple strategy of conflict resolution, considering the value more relevant, if it has been the last to change.
- Syncing of data structured as a tree or a graph is used in more sophisticated applications where the amount of data is large enough to send the database in its entirety at every update. In this case, conflicts have to be resolved at the level of individual objects, fields or relationships. We are primarily focused on this option.

So, we grabbed our knowledge into this article which I think might be very useful to everyone interested in the topic => Data Syncing in Core Data Based iOS apps (http://blog.denivip.ru/index.php/2014/04/data-syncing-in-core-data-based-ios-apps/?lang=en)

Comment: ^^^^^^ this is by far the best answer, guys!

Comment: I agree, Denis brought a lot into the topic + the article linkes is awesome. Also talks about the OT mentioned by DanielPaull. Answer by S.Lott is good but this is far more in depth.

Answer (score 31):

What you really need is [Operational Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_transformation) (OT).  This can even cater for the conflicts in many cases.

This is still an active area of research, but there are implementations of various OT algorithms around.  I've been involved in such research for a number of years now, so let me know if this route interests you and I'll be happy to put you on to relevant resources.

Comment: Daniel, a pointer to relevant resources would be appreciated.

Comment: I just re-read the wikipedia article.  It's come a long way and has many relevant references at the bottom of that page.  I would have pointed you to the work of Chengzheng Sun - his work is referenced from wikipedia. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_transformation.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 14):

The question is not crystal clear, but I'd look into [optimistic locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control) if I were you.
It can be implemented with a sequence number that the server returns for each record. When a client tries to save the record back, it will include the sequence number it received from the server. If the sequence number matches what's in the database at the time when the update is received, the update is allowed and the sequence number is incremented. If the sequence numbers don't match, the update is disallowed.

Comment: Sequence numbers are your friend here.  Think about persistent message queues.

Answer (score 13):

I built a system like this for an app about 8 years ago, and I can share a couple ways it has evolved as the app usage has grown.

I started by logging every change (insert, update or delete) from any device into a "history" table. So if, for example, someone changes their phone number in the "contact" table, the system will edit the contact.phone field, and also add a history record with action=update, table=contact, field=phone, record=[contact ID], value=[new phone number]. Then whenever a device syncs, it downloads the history items since the last sync and applies them to its local database. This sounds like the "transaction replication" pattern described above.

One issue is keeping IDs unique when items could be created on different devices. I didn't know about UUIDs when I started this, so I used auto-incrementing IDs and wrote some convoluted code that runs on the central server to check new IDs uploaded from devices, change them to a unique ID if there's a conflict, and tell the source device to change the ID in its local database. Just changing the IDs of new records wasn't that bad, but if I create, for example, a new item in the contact table, then create a new related item in the event table, now I have foreign keys that I also need to check and update.

Eventually I learned that UUIDs could avoid this, but by then my database was getting pretty large and I was afraid a full UUID implementation would create a performance issue. So instead of using full UUIDs, I started using randomly generated, 8 character alphanumeric keys as IDs, and I left my existing code in place to handle conflicts. Somewhere between my current 8-character keys and the 36 characters of a UUID there must be a sweet spot that would eliminate conflicts without unnecessary bloat, but since I already have the conflict resolution code, it hasn't been a priority to experiment with that.

The next problem was that the history table was about 10 times larger than the entire rest of the database. This makes storage expensive, and any maintenance on the history table can be painful. Keeping that entire table allows users to roll back any previous change, but that started to feel like overkill. So I added a routine to the sync process where if the history item that a device last downloaded no longer exists in the history table, the server doesn't give it the recent history items, but instead gives it a file containing all the data for that account. Then I added a cronjob to delete history items older than 90 days. This means users can still roll back changes less than 90 days old, and if they sync at least once every 90 days, the updates will be incremental as before. But if they wait longer than 90 days, the app will replace the entire database.

That change reduced the size of the history table by almost 90%, so now maintaining the history table only makes the database twice as large instead of ten times as large. Another benefit of this system is that syncing could still work without the history table if needed -- like if I needed to do some maintenance that took it offline temporarily. Or I could offer different rollback time periods for accounts at different price points. And if there are more than 90 days of changes to download, the complete file is usually more efficient than the incremental format.

If I were starting over today, I'd skip the ID conflict checking and just aim for a key length that's sufficient to eliminate conflicts, with some kind of error checking just in case. (It looks like YouTube uses 11-character random IDs.) The history table and the combination of incremental downloads for recent updates or a full download when needed has been working well.

Answer (score 1):

For delta (change) sync, you can use pubsub pattern to publish changes back to all subscribed clients, services like [pusher](http://www.pusher.com) can do this.

For database mirror, some web frameworks use a local mini database to sync server side database to local in browser database, partial synchronization is supported. Check [meteror](https://www.meteor.com/).

Answer (score -1):

This page clearly describes mosts scenarios of data synchronization with patterns and example code: [Data Synchronization: Patterns, Tools, & Techniques](https://www.datasyncbook.com/)

It is the most comprehensive source I found, considering whole of delta syncs, strategies on how to handle deletions and server-to-client and client-to-server sync. It is a very good starting point, worth a look.

Comment: It is an interesting resource however it's incomplete and I only found out about that after I purchased premium access. Only the first chapter is written. Looking at the site it's been more than a year since the last update so unfortunately it seems that the author gave up on it.