# How to remotely synchronize two sets?

Tags: java, synchronization, client-server

I need to synchronize two large sets of strings in Java, one of the on the client and the other on the server. Most probably the client is missing a couple of entries which it should receive from the server. I don't want to transfer all members, I want to minimize the communication and the computation on the server (the client may work harder).

Any idea besides divide-and-conquer?

I'm not asking about the communication technology or alike, I'm only interested in a good algorithm. I think something like what [version control does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413086/client-server-synchronization-pattern-algorithm/413136#413136) would be optimal, but I'm afraid I can't do it this way.

Comment: can the client modify the set.

Comment: Each has it's own set and changes can go both ways. Conflicts are improbable and quite irrelevant.

Comment: is this like hub & spoke where the server's changes are likely due to some other clients' changes

Comment: @Ron Some of them. The server drops some data, too. I'm afraid I need to think more about what exactly happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep a generation counter for the set on the server along with a change log for each generation. The client can request all changes since the last synchronization. It can then integrate those changes and also (if applicable) send back any remaining client-side changes since the last synchronization.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the right thing to do, I need to think more about it. But for the question as stated you gave the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can use socket, at first synchronize all members ans then using custom methods which add and remove members in local set and send data+instruction to other end
you can also use jmx active mq